# Looping through a list of dictionaries to find string match in value

Tags: python, loops, string-matching

I am looping through a a list of dictionaries called data. However, I want to then subsequently lookup whether or not a word under the words list shows up in one of the key,value pairs in the dictionaries within the data list. The keys are the same for every dictionary in the data list.

The problem is that while the loop works, the dictionary appears to be appended multiple times within the cleandata list. What am I missing?

This is what I have currently:

```
cleandata = []
data = [{'text':'some string1','another key':'some other text',...}, {'text':'some string2', 'another key':'some other text 2',...},{...},..]
words = ['word1','word2',...]

for d in data:
   for word in words:
     if word in d['text']:
       cleandata.append(d)
     else:
       continue
```

This gives me something like:

```
cleandata = [{'text':'word1','another key':'some other text',...},{'text':'word1','another key':'some other text',...},{'text':'word1','another key':'some other text',...},...{'text':'word2','another key':'some other text',...},{'text':'word2','another key':'some other text',...},... ]
```

Comment: You need something that says `if d not in cleandata`

Comment: At what point exactly does your program not behave as expected? What's the state of data at that point? To find out that place, extract a [mcve]. If it doesn't become clear by then, you can ask a much better question here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Break inner the loop on 1st found. and you don't need a continue

```
cleandata = []
data = [{'text':'some string1 word1 word2','another key':'some other text'}, {'text':'some string2 word1', 'another key':'some other text 2'}]
words = ['word1','word2']

for d in data:
    for word in words:
        if word in d['text']:
            cleandata.append(d)
            break
```

Comment: I like this answer because it shows exactly what is wrong. After understanding it, OP can choose to use `any()`.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

```
for d in data:
   if any(word in d['text'] for word in words):
       cleandata.append(d)
```

Which short-circuits on the first match.

That can be reduced to the list comprehension of:

```
[d for d in data if any(word in d['text'] for word in words)]
```

You can also use [set math](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) to eliminate the inner loop entirely:

```
words = set(['word1','word2'])
for d in data:
   if set(d['text'].split()) & words:
       cleandata.append(d)
```

Which may be significantly more efficient (depending on the actual data of course.)

That can be reduced to the list comprehension of:

```
[d for d in data if set(d['text'].split()) & words]
```